# Rake task to populate a database from a csv file, then assigning the members unique id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have never before worked with ruby or rails, and am attempting to rake data from a csv into a database, then assign the members of the database unique public id's of 4 digits. I'm under the impression that the first task is not difficult, but am unclear on how to proceed with the second. In order to maintain the same database, I would need to migrate the id's generated to the database through a second rake task, correct? How would I generate the id's in the first place? Is that a model on its own?